# Foreach range alphabetic and merge

Tags: php, html

We use the following foreach to display all categories. But we want to range them alphabetic and numeric ('A', 'Z'), ['#'] and also merge them. So that we get all alphabetic variables and group the results below. Also the alphabetic letter that does not have a result. That should get a custom css class.

How can we achieve this?

Current foreach:

```
<?php foreach ($subcategories as $subcat) { ?>
    <li class="menu-list-item">
        <a href="<?php echo $subcat->getUrl(); ?>" class="link link--hidden" title="<?php echo $subcat->getName(); ?>"><?php echo $subcat->getName(); ?></a>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```

What we want to achieve:

```
<ol class="landing-pages-list landing-pages-list-4-columns">
    <li class="landing-pages-list-item">
        <h3 class="landing-pages-list-title">A</h3>
        <ol class="landing-pages-list">
            <li class="landing-pages-list"><a href="<?php echo $subcat->getUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $subcat->getName(); ?></a></li>
            <li class="landing-pages-list"><a href="<?php echo $subcat->getUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $subcat->getName(); ?></a></li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="landing-pages-list-item landing-pages-list-item-no-items"><h3 class="landing-pages-list-title">B</h3></li>
    <li class="landing-pages-list-item">
        <h3 class="landing-pages-list-title">C</h3>
        <ol class="landing-pages-list">
            <li class="landing-pages-list"><a href="<?php echo $subcat->getUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $subcat->getName(); ?></a></li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: It is clear about the alphabetic, but what about the # ?

Comment: @belgacemfahmi Thanks! That should be used for values that start with a number.

Comment: Either collect your data in a multidimensional array first, grouped under the first letter / #. Then loop over A-Z and # to create your output, and check if the array contains entries for the current letter. If you don't want to build such a helper array first - then you can also loop over the data multiple times. Outer loop over A-Z/#, and inside a loop over the data, where for each record you check if its first character is a match. You will also have to keep a counter of those matches, to be able to determine whether the letter/# in the navigation list should get your special class, or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an idea, but i think you have to make more clean for your project.

I have added some lines to make it work, and you can test it in a sandbox php.

Please test the solution here : https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

And this tool to unminify the result HTML :
https://unminify.com/

If it is the a good idea for your problem clean it from the lines of test before you use it.

/* edit */

I have added the test of $subcategories count to make sure that the code execute only if $subcategories is not empty

```
<?php
/* just for the test */
$subcategories = array(
    1=>array('name'=>'A title 1', 'url'=>'A link 1'),
    2=>array('name'=>'D title 1', 'url'=>'D link 1'),
    3=>array('name'=>'a title 2', 'url'=>'a link 2'),
    5=>array('name'=>'9 title 1', 'url'=>'9 link 1'),
);
/* end test*/
?>
<?php if(count($subcategories)>0): ?>
<ol class="landing-pages-list landing-pages-list-4-columns">
<?php
$alphas = range('A', 'Z'); 
foreach($alphas as $key=>$char){
    $opened = false;
    foreach ($subcategories as $subcat) { 
        $subcat = (object)  $subcat; /* just for the test */
        if(preg_match("/^[{{$char}}]/i", $subcat->name)){
            if(!$opened){
                $opened = true;
                echo '<li class="landing-pages-list-item"><h3 class="landing-pages-list-title">'.$char.'</h3><ol class="landing-pages-list">';                  
            }               

            echo '<li class="landing-pages-list"><a href="'.$subcat->url.'" title="'.$subcat->name.'">'.$subcat->name.'</a></li>';
        }

    }

    if(!$opened){
        echo '<li class="landing-pages-list-item landing-pages-list-item-no-items"><h3 class="landing-pages-list-title">'.$char.'</h3></li>';
    } else { echo '</ol></li>'; }
    
}

$opened = false;
$char = "#";
foreach ($subcategories as $subcat) { 
    $subcat = (object)  $subcat; /* just for the test */
    if(preg_match("/^[\d]/i", $subcat->name)){
        if(!$opened){
            $opened = true;
                echo '<li class="landing-pages-list-item"><h3 class="landing-pages-list-title">'.$char.'</h3><ol class="landing-pages-list">';                  
        }               

        echo '<li class="landing-pages-list"><a href="'.$subcat->url.'" title="'.$subcat->name.'">'.$subcat->name.'</a></li>';
        }

    }

if(!$opened){
    echo '<li class="landing-pages-list-item landing-pages-list-item-no-items"><h3 class="landing-pages-list-title">'.$char.'</h3></li>';
} else { echo '</ol></li>'; }   
?>
</ol>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! I almost works perfect. But now it also displays the code if it can not find any $subcat value. Any idea how to update this, so that the code is not loaded when there is non $subcat?

Comment: @JGeer do you mean when your $subcategories is empty ?

Comment: Thanks, yes so if the foreach is empty, now it only loads all the <li class="landing-pages-list-item landing-pages-list-item-no-items">

Comment: @JGeer i have edited it to make sure that the code execute only if there are elements in $subcategories